# Syslog is getting filled with "[XTCOM]: PAM_NAM: pam_sm_authenticate: pam_get_user failed" every half an hour

Tags: c, pam

I have created "pam_sm_authenticate" module for doing pam related operations.A module "pam_sm_authenticate" is triggered every half an hour by  process
"gdm-session-worker".For each trigger syslog is getting filled with following message

"[XTCOM]: PAM_NAM: pam_sm_authenticate: pam_get_user failed".

I don't know why my  module is triggered by "gdm-session-worker" every half an hour and also why syslog is getting filled with above message for each trigger?

Could you please help me on this.

Please find the code snippet for "pam_sm_authenticate" module.

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate (pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {

```
int retval;
const char *pass = NULL;
char uFDN[512];

/* Get the username */
char *user;
retval = pam_get_user (pamh, &user, _("Username: "));
if (PAM_SUCCESS == retval)
{
    SYSLOG_MSG (0, "inside pam : user name obtained is : [%s]", user);
}

/* Get the Password */
retval = pam_get_item(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, &pass);
if (PAM_SUCCESS == retval)
{
```

Comment: I would guess that you configured your pam module in some common-auth section of the pam configuration.  If so everything on the system that calls pam_authenticate will hit it.  If you have specific process that you want your pam module to apply to, then you could probably limit this by simply narrowing the scope in which you configure your pam module.  Just configure it for the services that you care about and not all "common" services.